# How to add bottom padding to a table cell conditionally on word wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a borderless table layout with `<table><tr><td>` style tags. When the text inside the `<td>` cells are short enough that they don't wrap, visually the vertical position of each line of text is easily interpreted by an observer as being different rows. But when the text is long enough to word wrap, especially if it wraps several times, the eye can no longer easily distinguish between text that is wrapped and text that represents a new row.

While this could be solved by adding borders or fixed cell padding, I don't wish to do that because this is a component used for other things where it is desirable to keep it compact. Instead, I would like to add bottom padding (`padding-bottom`) to the `<td>` cells *whenever the text inside it wraps*, to create a visual separation between rows.

My current CSS is:

```
  td.value {
    padding-right: 1em;
    max-width: 100em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

While I could simply add `padding-bottom: 2em;` I don't want that extra space when there isn't any wrapping. Is there a way to do this on wrap only? I know I could conditionally set a class with JavaScript, but my code wouldn't know if wrapping is taking place. The number of columns and their widths is variable.

Mock up:

```css
  .wrapper {
     width: 75em;
  }

  td.name {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }

  td.value {
    padding-right: 1em;
    max-width: 100em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  .small {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }

  .red {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS1</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost.bogusdomain)(PORT=1530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE1)))</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS2</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost2.bogusdomain2)(PORT=1544)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE2)))</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS3</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bogushost3.bogusdomain3)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SERVICE3)))</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to examine.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier. Not easily done. I'm using Svelte which has a bunch of stuff that would clutter up the HTML. I'm unaware of how else to put together a working example.

Comment: Since this is a styling issue, you could use the rendered HTML with the CSS that goes with the table. Could you try that?

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier, that wasn't easy either because it's an SPA, HTML is rendered dynamically by Javascript. But I was able to copy the Body element in DevTools and reformat in a text editor and mock it up. Edited my question.

Comment: It looks like part of the problem is just  visually distinguishing between rows.  You could always just add CSS that stripes the rows so every even row (or odd row) has a slightly different background color. That way your eyes can easily scan across and see what data goes with what row

Comment: @imvain2, yes that is an option, just like borders. I would like to know if dynamic padding is possible because I prefer the look over striping or borders. For 90% of the uses of this component, no extra visual separation is needed because the text is short, and it would make it busy-looking to add separation effects 100% of the time. It's a generic pivot table component that I reuse for many things. I suppose I can just tell the component to add space when it's used to display data likely to be long, but I'd first like to know if there's a CSS solution that handles this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you can't use JavaScript because it can't detect word wrapping. What you can do is determine the default height that you want the TDs to be. Then in JavaScript loop through the TDs and if any have an `offsetHeight` larger than your default, add the class.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td.value");

const maxHeight = 30;

tds.forEach((td) => {
  if(td.offsetHeight > maxHeight){
    td.classList.add("padBottom");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
     width: 75em;
  }

  td.name {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }

  td.value {
    padding-right: 1em;
    max-width: 100em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  .small {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }

  .red {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .padBottom{
    padding-bottom:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS1</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum sa
      d sa<br>
      a
      sdsad</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      Lorem Impsum</td>
     </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS2</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdas jdsoaidjsa90d usa0du asdj msadmsadm lsamd lsamd klsamd lksamd lksamd lksm dlsam dlmsalkm dlksamd lmldl smald msakld mlsak mdl</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="name svelte-148wmfe">
      ALIAS3</td>
       <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
   oaskdp okasp od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdkdadk aoaskdp okasp od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdkdadsp od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdkdadk p od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asddpask poaskdp okasp od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdkdadk aspdo sp od</td>
      <td class="value svelte-148wmfe small">
      asdkdadk aspdo ksapodk </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: I had to use a different method (rather a bit more complex) to work with Svelte, but the general concept of waiting until DOM update and then interrogating the elements to compute sizing and adding a class afterwards works, though it isn't very performant. I've done this before, I don't know why I didn't think of it this time. You helped jog my memory. Thanks much!